# Audio Record using Android NDK

Tags: android, android-ndk

I try to record audio using android ndk. people say I can use "frameworks/base/media/libmedia/AudioRecord.cpp". but it is in kernel. how can I access and use it?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The C++ libmedia library is not part of the public API. Some people use it, but this is highly discouraged because it might break on some devices and/or in a future Android release.

I developed an audio recording app, and trust me, audio support is very inconsistent across devices, it's **very tricky**, so IMO using libmedia directly is a bad idea.

The only way to capture raw audio with the public API is to use the Java [AudioRecord](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioRecord.html) class. It will gives you PCM data, which you can then choose to pass to your C optimized routines.

Alternatively, although that's a bit harder, you could write a C/C++ wrapper around the Java AudioRecord class, as it is possible to instantiate Java objects and call methods through JNI.

Comment: This answer is outdated.
Use the OpenSL ES multimedia framework in the android NDK instead.

Answer (score 4):

May be a little-bit outdated but:

1. the safest way of playing/recording audio in native code is by using OpenSL ES interfaces.
   Nevertheless it's available only on android 2.3+ and for now works over generic AudioFlinger API.
2. the more robust and simple way is using platform source-codes to get AudioFlinger headers and some generic libmedia.so used for linking on the build stage.
   Device-dependent libmedia.so should be preloaded at application initialization stage for AudioFlinger to work normally (generally it is done automatically). Take a note that some vendors try changing AudioFlinger internals (by ambiguous reasons), so you may encounter some memory or behavior issues.

In my experience AudioFlinger worked on all (2.0+) devices but sometimes required allocating more memory for the object than it was supposed by default implementation.

Finally saying OpenSL ES is a wrapper with dynamically loadable C-interface which allows using it with any particular AudioFlinger implementation. It is pretty complicated for simple usage, and may have even more overhead than using Java AudioTrack/AudioRecord because of internal threading, buffering, etc..
So consider using Java or not-so-safe native AudioFlinger until Google implements some high-performance audio interface (which is doubtful for now).

Answer (score 2):

The OpenSL Es API is available from Android 2.3 on (API-Level 9)